# Is it possible to create a char column which is always lowercase?

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a table like:

```
create table project_types (
  id char(20) not null unique default 'xxx'
};
```

To use it from other tables as:

```
create table other_table (
  ...
  fk_ptype char(20),
  fk_ptype_on_other_table" foreign key (fk_ptype) references project_type(id)
);
```

The catch is I'd want all values inserted into `project_types` to become automatically lowercase: I don't want to be making the conversion on each possible query, I want a table that no matter what I throw at it, it returns back lowercase tokens.

I'm thinking about making a trigger on insert an on update, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to impose such a restriction. Also, this solution means I'll have to make the conversion on deletions.

For the ones that may suggest that I do this with enums: the types are dynamic, so I prefer this approach.

**UPDATE 2017.04.17:** The idea of this question is not to put controls/transformations everywhere in the stack: if database can handle whatever you throw at it, then you don't have to **1.** check/transform in the front-end, **2.** check/transform in the back-end code, and finally **3.** check/transform in the database. You just avoid doing 1 and 2 because you know database will handle whatever you throw at it and that you'll have correct data when you `select` from it.

I'm tempted to choose [@herbert-pimentel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3637000/herbert-pimentel) answer, but it seems the same approach cannot bo used for `delete` (I tried setting and on-delete trigger using the same function but it didn't work).

Comment: What do you mean by the "conversion on deletions"?

Comment: @joanolo I mean that while the triggers for insert and update will automatically convert saved text into lowercase, I'll have to *explicitly* use a `lower()` when I try to do something like: `delete from myTable where id = 'Text no lowerCased'`. Maybe there are on-delete triggers, I'm not aware of them, I'm just thinking about it now as I write

Comment: There are on delete triggers, but they are not meant for this purpose; they do not *change* the SQL you generate (which is what you would need). If you really need to do such things, use one special type of text "citext" (needs to install a package). Check: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html

Answer (score 3):

how about a trigger with before insert or update to ensure/transform your data lower case;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fun_trg_lowercase()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin 
  NEW.my_char_field = lowercase(NEW.my_char_field);  
  RETURN NEW;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER biu_lowercase_field
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON mytable
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE fun_trg_lowercase();
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Check constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS):

```
create table project_types (
    id char(20) not null unique default 'xxx'
    check (id = lower(id))
);
```

Comment: he wants auto case change, so needs trigger or rules

Comment: @VaoTsun This is half the answer as a trigger is not that reliable.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: Why isn't a trigger reliable?

Comment: @joanolo Because programmers are not reliable.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: you can apply that rule to *anything*. You can misstype a `CHECK` constraint as well as you can make a mistake writing a trigger.

Comment: @joanolo execution of triggers can be turned off, for instance. Yes, programmers can *agree* on to never do that, but that's no better than an agreement of inserting only lower-cased input in the first place.

Comment: @pozs: you can also have a constraint and drop it or alter it ... (unless you restrict it via privileges..., which I guess you can also do with triggers)

Comment: @joanolo yes, probably. but altering or dropping the constraint is design change, but temporarily disabling a trigger is usually not considered one (and it is not that unusual to do that). i'm not saying that a trigger solution is not valid, but in OP's case is a lot more easier to put this logic in the application's repository layer instead. and a constraint in the db can do the integrity check.

Comment: While I like the idea of database telling me about a broken condition, in the case of a simple transformation like this one I prefer database doing the work automagically :) I tried this approach in conjunction with the triggers and it doesn't allow me to insert bad (uppercase) strings: the check comes after the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a special type of data for this purpose, called `CITEXT` (=case insensitive text). It is an additionally supplied module standard within PostgreSQL.

Citing the [PostgreSQL documentation on CITEXT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html):

> F.8.1. Rationale
>
> The standard approach to doing case-insensitive matches in PostgreSQL has been to use the lower function when comparing values, for example
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tab WHERE lower(col) = LOWER(?);
> ```
>
> This works reasonably well, but has a number of drawbacks:
>
> It makes your SQL statements verbose, and you always have to remember to use lower on both the column and the query value.
>
> It won't use an index, unless you create a functional index using lower.
>
> If you declare a column as `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY`, the implicitly generated index is case-sensitive. So it's useless for case-insensitive searches, and it won't enforce uniqueness case-insensitively.
>
> The citext data type allows you to eliminate calls to lower in SQL queries, and allows a primary key to be case-insensitive. citext is locale-aware, just like text, which means that the matching of upper case and lower case characters is dependent on the rules of the database's LC_CTYPE setting. Again, this behavior is identical to the use of lower in queries. But because it's done transparently by the data type, you don't have to remember to do anything special in your queries.

So, in your specific case, you just would need to do:

One time:

```
CREATE EXTENSION citext ;

CREATE TABLE project_types 
(
    id citext PRIMARY KEY default 'xxx'
);

CREATE TABLE other_table 
(
     /* ... */
   fk_ptype citext,
   fk_ptype_on_other_table foreign key (fk_ptype) references project_type(id)
);
```

... and then, do *nothing* to your queries. Don't have any extra constraints and don't have any (apparently *feared*) trigger.

Comment: Beautiful extension :) Will prove useful for other use cases I have around here. But for this specific case this doesn't save the text lowercased: `insert into project_types (id) values ('UNO')` , then `select id from project_types` gives me 'UNO'. :/

Comment: If you need to *store* it lowercased, then add the trigger.